# trick console prog to make it think it writes to terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, console, stdout

Many terminal programs will behave differently depending on the STDOUT destination, either terminal or pipe or file. Usually they will remove colors. There are usually command line options for some of them to keep colors or formatting or anything else that is intended only for direct terminal output. But those options are not always present and it takes time to find them thus I need a generic way to trick the program so that it thinks that STDOUT is terminal, not a pipe. How to achieve this?

Comment: You want to fake it so that it believes it *is* a terminal even when it isn't?

Comment: bingo, amazing thinking

Comment: You first have to know how the program determines if its standard output is a terminal.

Comment: You might also look into how to use allocate a pseudoterminal and use that, instead of a pipe, as the standard output for your program.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools for this, they basically create a pty for your command.

The best known is probably `expect`: http://expect.sf.net

Alternatively, `empty`: http://empty.sf.net
There are several examples in that page, have a look.

For simple cases, `script -c 'mycommand'` may be a viable alternative.

And `tmux`, which is powerful and pretty easy to script.